# On a family of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, arithmetic-geometry

Investigating experimentally a topic (somewhat related to Bernoulli convolutions), I came across families of polynomials and I wonder whether they belong to some well-known family. A closely related family is (I think) related to Pisot numbers, so it is not completely hopeless that my polynomials have some number theoretic property.

The first family is
$$F_k(X) = X^{k+3}-2X^{k+2}+X-1 \quad k\ge 0$$
and the second one
$$G_k(X) = X^{k+4}-2X^{k+3}+X^{k+2}-1 \quad k\ge 0.$$
Other polynomials I get, who probably belong to families that I do not have identified are
$$C(X) = x^6-2X^5+X^3-X^2+X-1 \quad D(X) = X^5-2X^4+X^2-1$$
$$ E(X)  = X^6-2X^5+X^4-X^3+X^2-1.$$

Do these polynomials ring a bell to any number theorist, by any chance?

Comment: In $E(X)$, you don't really want an exponent $k+2$, do you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson no, indeed!